# Create OpenApi 3 Documentation from Spring Rest Project at Build Time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I am trying to create an OpenApi 3 Documentation (a json file with the openapi 3 specs) for my Spring Rest Project at build time.

The only Plugin I found to create a documentation with spring was the spring-boot-maven-plugin from Spring.
https://springdoc.org/#maven-plugin

But this plugin needs to start the spring Project to create the Documentation.
Is there any other way to create the docu without starting the Project?

Comment: have you found the answer

Comment: not really. I created a new Project which starts my Application with the minimum needed controller classes and then i got the OpenAPI Json from that. It's not really what i searched for, but i haven't found a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i also searching the same. Right now handled  using @Conditional property by passing explicitly at server.(I am also not getting any clues). If you found anything please post as an answer.